# Is it possible to download the statements zip for Upwork via the REST API?

Tags: rest, upwork-api

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to generate a statements zip file for Upwork using the REST API. I would like to be able to specify a start and end date and generate a zip containing the transactions for the period (invoices, payments, receipts, etc).

I have applied for an access token, which is apparently a process that requires you to raise a support ticket, apply for an access token, provide proof of ID (which I've already done for my freelancer, company and agency account!).

I am asking this question, because I don't have access to test out the API yet and would like to understand whether or not this is at all possible.